# Php search with multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So, I have defined a function for searching from DB and passing the results to ajax.

```
function do_search() {
    $search=$_POST['dname'];
    global $wpdb;
    $sql="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE `firstname` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `lastname` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR  `department`LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `phone` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `job_title` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `cell_phone` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `image`LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `email` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `address` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `room` LIKE '%{$search}%';";
    $result2=$wpdb->get_results($sql);
    echo json_encode($result2);
    wp_die();
}
```

But my problem is its working only with one word. I tried  explode the $_POST value with " ". and then making foreach and build multiple queries, like $query[i]  but i cant get no response?

How do implement that when echoing the result - then it echoes result where every word is compared to those field entries?

Comment: not clear what you are asking

Comment: I can echo only single word search at the moment. Multiple word query just results nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exploding search query and producing tons of conditions, You can use simple "trick":

```
$search = $_POST['dname'];
$search = str_replace(' ', '%', $search);

$query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE col1 LIKE '%{$search}%' OR col2 LIKE '%{$search}%' ";
```

Don't forget to escape input or parametrizing query.

Answer (score -1):

Exploding and multiple query criterias is the only option here.

this is wrong to say that making a $search variable like this will make it multi word searching the same column. It will not. Because the result of spaces replaced with pecentage wild card will be something like %word1%word2% using above code and multiple percentages will make it search BOTH words not a single one, in that particular column, so multiple percentage wildcards are treated in SQL as AND meaning both should meet in order to be selected, whereas I think we are trying to create a multi word query that treats as OR meaning either word1 or word2 exist, the record should be selected (hence requirement for explode and as many likes required as many words user entered), no this trick of replacing spaces with pecentages, will not work in multiple words.